# DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've a PL/SQL procedure that is simply:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COMPILE_VIEWS AS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema('schema_name');
END COMPILE_VIEWS;
```

When I call the procedure, it seems to loop without actually compile any object...

Comment: How do you notice that it is looping, and how do you see that objects are not compiled?

Comment: I'm curious: your procedure name is `COMPILE_VIEWS`, but you're recompiling every object in the schema. Does this schema contain only views?

Comment: wolφi: When I run directly EXEC DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema('schema_name'); it's done in less than 2-3 minutes, when I run the procedure, it runs during 20 minutes. I've tested that multiple times.

Comment: Bob Jarvis: Actually, no, but the views represent something like 30-40 % of the total objects (all included), and this is for compiling the views I run that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it manually- so you can debug it as well.

```
SELECT 'alter ' 
  || DECODE( object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE','TYPE BODY','TYPE', object_type) 
  || ' ' 
  || object_name 
  || ' compile ' 
  ||DECODE( object_type,'PACKAGE BODY','body','TYPE BODY','body') 
  ||';' 
FROM all_objects 
WHERE owner ='schema_name' 
AND status !='VALID' ;
```

then alter the invalids one.

Answer (score 2):

If schema objects are used by someone, those objects can't be compiled until they are released. That looks like an "indefinite loop" - *nothing happens*.

Compile them when nobody's working, i.e. during the *off* hours (at night?).

Answer (score 2):

You can monitoring the recompile invalid objects by repeating the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) "NumberOfInvalidObject"
FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OWNER='Your_desired_schema_name_here' AND STATUS='INVALID';
```

Put that code in SQL Developer and pressing F5. You will realize the number of invalid objects are decreasing ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found my answer somewhere else. As someone pointed out, only views need to be compile, so, here is the code (working), that is an alternative to DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COMPILE_VIEWS AS 

  cursor OBJECTS is
  select object_name, object_type, status
  from USER_OBJECTS
  where object_type in ('VIEW')
    and object_name != 'COMPILE_SCHEMA'
    and status = 'INVALID'
  order by object_name;
  --
  cmd            varchar2(300);
  msg            varchar2(2000);
  COMPILE_ERROR  exception;
  pragma EXCEPTION_INIT (COMPILE_ERROR, -24344);
begin
  dbms_output.enable(1000000);

  for o in objects loop
        cmd := 'alter '||o.object_type||' '||o.object_name||' compile';
      begin
        execute immediate cmd;
        msg := rpad('Compiled '||lower(o.object_type),25)||o.object_name;
      exception 
        when COMPILE_ERROR then
          msg := rpad('Compiled '||lower(o.object_type),25)||rpad(o.object_name,35)||' COMPILE ERROR';        
        when OTHERS then
          msg := rpad('Compiled '||lower(o.object_type),25)||rpad(o.object_name,35)||sqlerrm;
      end;
      dbms_output.put_line(rtrim(msg));
  end loop;

END COMPILE_VIEWS;
```

Then run it:

```
begin
  COMPILE_VIEWS();
end;
```

Works like a charm.